# How do you solve this image caching issue?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to place an image in a running header.  I can display the image if is not part of the running header, but if I put it in the running header I get:

The image at '/resource/1564841822000/MediaProLogo' has a dimension set to 0. This can happen when the image is cached and later used with a different CSS style. Add a '?style=YourCssStyle' query parameter to the image URL to prevent caching.

```
<head >
    <style >

        @page { 

            @top-left {
                content: element(top-left-div);
            }
        }
        .top-left-div { 
            display: block;  
            position: running(top-left-div);
        } 

</style >
```

.
.
.

Full code:

```
<apex:page controller="RenewalPDFController" applyBodyTag="false" cache="false" renderAs="pdf" >
<head >
    <style >

        @page { 
            @top-left {
                content: element(top-left-div);
            }
            @top-right {
                content: element(top-right-div);
            }
            @bottom-left { 
                content: element(bottom-left-div);
            } 
            @bottom-right { 
                content: element(bottom-right-div)
            } 
            margin-bottom: 8em;
        }
        .pagenumber:before 
            {
            content: counter(page);
        }
        .pagecount:before 
        {
            content: counter(pages);
        }
        .top-left-div {  
            position: running(top-left-div);
        } 
        .top-right-div { 
            display: block;  
            color: #838383;
            margin-left: 420px;
            position: running(top-right-div);
        } 
        .bottom-left-div { 
            display: block;  
            color: #838383;
            position: running(bottom-left-div);
        } 
        .bottom-right-div { 
            display: block;  
            color: #838383;
            margin-left: 420px;
            position: running(bottom-right-div);
        } 

    </style>
</head>

<div class="top-left-div" >
    <img src="{!$Resource.MediaProLogo}" width="50%" height="50%" />
</div>
<div class="top-right-div" >
    <apex:outputText value="Sales Order" style="color: #838383; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;" /> 
</div>
Test
<div style="page-break-after:always;" ></div>
Test
<div style="page-break-after:always;" ></div>
Test
<div class="bottom-left-div">
    <div>
        Confidential and Proprietary
        <br/>
        {!opportunity.Contract_Controlling_Document__c}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-right-div">
    Page <span class="pagenumber" ></span> of <span class="pagecount" ></span>
</div>
```

I cleared the cache in my browser.  I created a new VF page with this code, but I still get the same error.

Thanks.

After posting: I resolved this by using @top-right-corner instead of @top-right.

Comment: unable to reproduce. can you show minimum code to reproduce (or full code)

Comment: See full code now.

Comment: The problem seems related to having the top-right-div included.